# CSS: The difference between absolute inside absolute and relative inside absolute

Tags: html, css, web

I have recently tried a CSS project to draw a flag of a country.

**Here is my code:**

```css
    div.flag {
      width: 900px;
      height: 600px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    div.flag > div {
      position: absolute;
      top: 150px;
      width: 900px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    div.flag > div > div {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: relative;
      left: 350px;
      top: 50px;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 5rem;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    div.flag > div > div > p {
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flag">
    <p>The Flag</p>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>of Laos</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I don't specify the margin of the text "of Laos" and position of the circle set to relative, the text margin pushes the circle down like this:

[image]

But when I set the position of circle to absolute and not specify the text margin, the circle position comes out correct:

[image]

What is happening exactly? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when using `relative`, the positioning happens relative to the normal flow of the element, i.e., if you say `top: 10px;` the element will just move 10px from it's intended position.

When using `absolute`, the element gets removed from normal flow & the positioning happens relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. so, 'top: 10px;' will position the element 10px down from the positioned ancestors top.

You can get more info about this using the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#syntax)

Comment: Imagine what the circle would look like if you didn't put any positioning to it, what would it look like normally. Now when you make it `relative` it will remain in normal-flow what it means is that the browser will reserve the space for the circle on screen as it would do normally, but now you can position the circle relative to it's normal position. Where as in case of absolute the space is not reserved & you position relative to the positioned ancestor. I hope that helps.

Comment: Oh! I fully understand that when I set position of the div to `static`, eveything makes sence. Thank You!!